# Memcached return not stored

Tags: php, memcached

I'm a newbie with `Memcached` and I'm trying to use this feature for have an editable configuration over the air in my application.

So I need to store some data, for doing this I did:

```
class Settings
{
    private $_config = array();
    private static $_memcached = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        self::$_memcached = new Memcached();
        self::$_memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

        $file = 'config.php'; //return $config content
        require_once $file;

        $this->_config = $config;

        foreach($config as $item => $value)
        {
            self::$_memcached->add($item, $value);
            echo self::$_memcached->getResultMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the instruction of the documentation available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php).
Unlucky I get this error:

> NOT STORED

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. The Memcached::getResultCode() will return Memcached::RES_NOTSTORED if the key already exists.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar The problem is that the key not exist. So should be added.

Comment: You use `foreach`. Check all items from array are not exist in memcached.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar maybe this happen 'cause I declare a new Memcached class each time a new request is shunt by index.php?

Comment: ok. try to add one more `foreach` with delete. just for checking. `foreach ($config as $item => $value)  { self::$_memcached->delete($item); foreach($config as $item => $value)
        {
            self::$_memcached->add($item, $value);
            echo self::$_memcached->getResultMessage();
        }`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Now seems working, but I don't understand, why two foreach? What's happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comments. Some key exist in memcached. And you try to add key one more time. It is the reason. Try to add inspection before add. It  should be something like this:

```
foreach ($config as $item => $value) {
    if (!(bool)self::$_memcached->get($item)) {
        self::$_memcached->add($item, $value);
        echo self::$_memcached->getResultMessage();
    }
}
```